# Github setup in Eclipse (Sage X3)

Tags: eclipse, github

I am working eclipse setup with sage in that I have to link GitHub repository to x3 project. I am able to add the project to GitHub successfully but getting an error while compiling the code:

[image]

Can anyone experience this earlier? If anyone is there help me on that.

Thanks,
Madhava

Comment: Which error you get for which code of which language when compiling it how and where? And how is this related to Eclipse and GitHub?

Comment: Thanks for your response.
It is related to X3(4GL) language which is from SAGE and they provided X3 studio nothing but eclipse and it is used for debugging the code. Please find the picture which I added

Answer (score 0):

try updating your IDE and GIT plugin:

[Git Eclipse version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEguJ.png)

It might work for you.

This is the eclipse version I use [eclipse version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZEaC.png)

Check your git view in eclipse too
[Git repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdM7T.png)

You can associate your workspace with GITHUB Desktop, it works fine and makes commits easy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).